# How to add a file to version control in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

When I create a new file in IntelliJ IDEA, it gets automatically ignored by Subversion, no matter what, and it is impossible to commit the file. While in Spring Tool Suite all I need to do is right click and select **Team>Add to version control** in order to commit that new file. I have try several approaches with no success since many options are disabled.

Comment: Do you select the option: Add to Version Control while creating?

Comment: I have found a temporary solution: install Tortoise and go to the folder that contains your file and then right click on the file, select ToritoiseSVN>Add, then go back to IntelliJ and you will be able to commit the new file with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: the problem was that a parent directory was being ignored by SVN, so I searched directory by directory starting with the current directory until I found a parent directory that had a configuration to ignore all directories, for this task I used tortoise, just right click and select TortoiseSVN>Properties look for ignored files and delete the directory you want to synchronize, if no you don´t find the directory look for (*).

Answer (score 1):

> When I create a new file in IntelliJ IDEA, it gets automatically ignored by Subversion

What do you mean by automatically? There is no any automatic rules - file is either configured as ignored, or not. Make sure there is no svn:ignore property set on the folder (probably not since other tools work).

Also, make sure nothing wrong is added to Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files. The description looks like you have the entire project or sources folder added there as ignored

Comment: It seems to me that the issue is related to SVN configuration rather than IntelliJ.

The folder is not configured as ignored, and when I create a new file IntelliJ does not even asks if I want to add it to version control, despite it's configured to ask every time I create a new file.

Comment: You mentioned it works in other tools, so I think Internal ignore files list of IntelliJ is related. BTW, you mentioned file gets ignored by IntelliJ - how do you know? Is it color-hightlighted as ignored?

Comment: Yes Dimitry, it is in olive green, which means that the file is being ignored.